# Where can I find C++ code samples for HMM (hidden Markov model) as it relates to gesture recognition?

Tags: markov-process, hidden-markov-model

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Gesture recognition is rather a specific application; if you can't find such using a search engine, you'll have to get lucky to get some here.  Also, C++ code samples for HMM will be rather lengthy.  I'm sure this is what you'd like, ideally, but is there something less restrictive that would be useful to you?

Comment: any kind of statistical pattern matching would be great - simpler the better, frankly. I'm no programming genius, and the code needs to be pretty light anyway

Comment: What kind of data are you working with?

Comment: cursor input (x/y coordinates, floating point between -2 and 2)

Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These might help, although they aren't specific to your problem:

[Univ. of Alberta stuff](http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~lindek/hmm.htm)

[Daniel Roggen homepage](http://danielroggen.net/software_dhmm.html)

[General Hidden Markov Model library (sourceforge)](http://ghmm.sourceforge.net/)

[koders.com code](http://www.koders.com/cpp/fid0B05230AA1A9200AC6D6AC93FA89219953D2220D.aspx)

Comment: excellent. I've found a much cheaper solution, but will use those if that fails. Thanks again.

Comment: i'm interested in this problem too. what kind of solution?